# PHPExcel Style getting default number format

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have the following code

```
$xl = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = xl->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
$sheet->getStyle('A')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
$format = $sheet->getStyle('A')->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
```

I'd expect $format to contain `#,##0.00` but it contains `General`.

Am I missing something?

PHPExcel v. 1.7.6

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PHPExcel does not support row or column styles: styles are applied to cells

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
```

or to ranges of cells

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1:B2')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
```

and version 1.7.6 is very dated now, you really should upgrade to a more recent version

Comment: Getting FatalErrorException `undefined method PHPExcel::getStyle()`, If try with `$sheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');` getting Sheet does not exist. I am using Excel template.

Comment: @151291 - First off.... if you have problems, then you ask a proper question, you don't simply make a comment to an answer to somebody else's question.... that way, you can also post your code properly, with those few extra lines that might help explain what is causing your problem

Comment: But the error says that you're not calling `getStyle()` against a worksheet, but against a workbook.... what we can't see is why you're getting a workbook object

Answer (score -1):

```
// getActiveSheet() is required to apply number format

$object->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(25);
$object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F8')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
$object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, 8, @$mfArr->total);
```