# Excel sheet generated for an html page not showing decimal part in 3 decimal format

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

```
<?php  echo $num > 0 ? number_format((float)$num, 3, '.', '') : number_format((float)$num_neg, 3, '.', '');?>
```

The code is used to display the number with 3 decimal format in excel page,but the generated excel page does not show the number with 3 decimal format if the number does not contain decimal values.If we concatenate any string values the generated excel sheet will show the number with decimal values correctly.Is their any solution for this.

Comment: Try this: https://degreedocumentation.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/how-to-format-a-number-cell-in-phpexcel/ but if u dont use it to e.g count, sum etc. just put it like a string.

Answer (score 3):

To show the original format of a cell's content append at the start of the value one `'`: that force excel to view the content as text.

```
<?php
echo $num > 0 
    ? "'".number_format((float)$num, 3, '.', '') 
    : "'".number_format((float)$num_neg, 3, '.', '');
?>
```

This solution work fine if the file is a .csv format.
For excel file .xls using PHPEXCEL see [PHPExcel Style getting default number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170401/phpexcel-style-getting-default-number-format)

Comment: append at the start of the value one `'`

Comment: Your solution was helpful, but the output obtained contain a quote at start of the number(eg: '0.000)

Comment: Are you generating a .excel file or .csv?

Comment: we are generating .xls file.

Comment: Are you using PHPExcel?

Comment: Yes .
@user2342558

Comment: In that case see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170401/phpexcel-style-getting-default-number-format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136743/discussion-between-jibin-k-john-and-user2342558).